# How can I remove the hash # from a redirected URL from an external page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I make an anchor call in the middle of a different page than the one I'm navigating, the browser's url removes the hash # from the anchor, but returns to the initial value.

The big problem is that when I finally get rid of the hash, the anchor hyperlink stops working.

I have tried different options to solve this problem, but for the moment none has worked.

```
<a href="index.php#has1" onclick="changeURL()">Seccion1</a>

function changeURL() {
  window.history.replaceState( {} , 'index.php#has1', 'index.php' );
  alert("the url changes, but when I close alert, url returns to its origin");
}
```

Other options without success:

```
//window.history.pushState(null, "", "index.php");
//window.location.hash='';


<script>
    $('index.php#promo').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        //the rest of the function is the same.
    });
</script>
```

Expected result: "www.mysite.com/index.php"

Current result: "www.mysite.com/index.php.#has1"

Comment: What is the problem having the hash in the first place?

Comment: The anchor stops working. Just change the page, instead of changing the page and go to the height of the anchor.